# Copy files from a source folder recursively to destination/*file_extension*(ex. "txt") folder

Tags: recursive

This is my code, something in the rec_copy() function isn't working properly, the extension named folders are created in the destination folder but the files are not copied there.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
        echo "Usage: $0 <source> <destination>"
        exit
fi

if [ ! -d $1 ]
then
        echo "Source folder does not exist"
        exit
fi

if [ -d $2 ]
then
        rm -r $2
        mkdir $2
else
        mkdir $2
fi

extension=`ls -l $1 | grep -v "^d" | awk '{ print $10; }' | sed 's/^.*\.//g'`
for f in $extension
do
        if [ ! -d $1/$f ]
        then
                mkdir $2/$f
        fi
done

rec_copy(){
folder=`ls $1`
for f in $folder
do
        dest=`echo "$f" | sed 's/.*\.//g'`
        if [ -f $1/$f ]
        then
                cp $1/$f $HOME/$2/$dest
        elif [ -d $1/$f ]
        then
                rec_copy $1/$f
        fi
done
}

rec_copy $1
```

Comment: Sure `$10` is the correct file name? What if file names contain spaces?

Comment: It's a recursive function of course I'm calling it inside, that is the point. The $10 is the 10th column in ls -l, which is the file name itself. I think that the "cp $1/$f $HOME/$2/$dest" command is not working like I want it to work. If you just test the program you will see what the problem is.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/79a9nGI) It's 10 in my case, ignoring the situation when there is a space in the name. I'm positive that's not the problem. When I copy the files in the home directory it all works great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in case someone ever needs it:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
        echo "Usage: $0 <izvor> <destinacija>"
        exit
fi

if [ ! -d "$1" ]
then
        echo "Izvorniot folder ne postoi"
        exit
fi

if [ -d "$2" ]
then
        rm -r "$2"
        mkdir "$2"
else
        mkdir "$2"
fi

extension=`ls -l "$1" | grep -v "^d" | awk '{ print $10; }' | sed 's/^.*\.//g'`
for f in $extension
do
        if [ ! -d "$1/$f" ]
        then
                mkdir "$2/$f"
        fi
done

rec_copy(){
folder=`ls "$1"`
for f in $folder
do
        dest=`echo "$f" | sed 's/.*\.//g'`
        to=`cp "$1/$f" "$2/$dest"`

        if [ -f "$1/$f" ]
        then
                echo "$to"
        elif [ -d "$1/$f" ]
        then
                rec_copy "$1/$f" "$2"
        fi
done
}

rec_copy "./$1" "./$2"
```